# Ubuntu 12.04 suddenly will not boot after compiz crash on lockscreen

Tags: compiz, boot-failure, data-recovery, display-manager

Yesterday i went to work and closed my laptop. When i got home I couldn't get the lock screen to come back up. ctrl+alt+f2 to get to a terminal and Tried to kill compiz, compiz was not running so I tried to restart it got an error opening the display so i tried to restart lightdm again couldn't open display. so I restarted and now I am stuck on the loading screen. I tried booting in recovery mode and all options hang except root, but i'm stuck with read only. booting from a live cd I can mount the drive but again stuck with read only. I'm completely stuck here. checking my default-display-manager returns "/usr/sbin/elsa" as the only line and can't edit it. I've got an 11.10 live cd and my /home is encrypted so i can't try to back anything up at the moment either. How can i resolve this or at the least back up some of my data? Please help!

Comment: So, I went through and tried out changing some things. Change default-display-manager to standard settings for lightdm that I found on this site. Still no boot. I copied xorg.conf.failsafe to xorg.conf, still no boot. I would love to be able to save this install someway. fsck shows file system intact. yet still can't open the display manager. When I try to load in failsafe graphic mode somewhere along the process it freezes. ctrl+c and it starts a string of thing ending up at the e17 login (instead of the gnome it normally does) and I can't login with my password. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get `elsa` working, but by running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` I was able to resolve the boot issue.